# How do I allow spaces to be input in Bootstrap Select?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I want to be able to type a space (keycode=32) but bootstrap-select does not let me type it.  Any idea how I can allow spaces to be input?

I'm using v1.11.0

[image: Bootstrap-select v1.11.0]

Comment: Can you make a demo reproducing the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be something else is preventing you from entering space, bootstrap-select does no prevent your from entering spaces, checkout demo below:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.11.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.11.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
  <option>Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
  <option>Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
  <option>Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have the same issue as the original poster and although your snippet works I cannot figure out why, and this *does* appear to have been reported on the project site -- https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/1249 -- but in a way earlier version than what I am using...

Comment: @ChristopherKing may be something related to version of bootstrap? OP didn't posted the code so its bit hard to reason exact cause.

Comment: thanks for reminding me; I am still looking into exactly why but in my setup the problem only seems to occur when the selectlist is used within a bootstrap modal; in places where I use the searchable selectlist outside of the modal there is no problem with entering a space but in the modal a space will collapse the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

```
//CAN ENTER SPACES
$(function() {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
          liveSearch: false,
          showSubtext: true
    });
});

//CANNOT ENTER SPACES
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
          liveSearch: false,
          showSubtext: true
    });
});
```